# html5 video seekbar disable in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html, video

I need to disable the default functionality of video seek bar live videos. I am using brightcove videos and I coul disable seekbar functionality by setting css property `pointer-events` to `none` and it worked fine.

```
.vjs-slider{ pointer-events: none }
```

But the same wont work in ios devices. Any idea how to make it happen in ios devices?

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h2nLxed9/)**

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

#### solution1: Put a cover on it

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.cover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
  <div class="cover">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### solution2: remove "controls" attr